# Webtrends tracking parameters on our site URLs are causing duplicate content and SEO problems

Tags: google-search, duplicate-content

We have some issue with duplicate content on Google SERP. The problem is that we are using Click Tracking on Webtrends that adds a parameter after the URL. This is what a URL can look like when Webtrends loads on the webpage: `https://www.example.com/private/loan.html?WT.ac=xxxxx-xxxx_xxx_animate_loan_button-v1&WT.svl=Menu`

As I am aware Google Crawl the links and adds also the parameters so this content is duplicated because if you remove everything after `?WT.ac` the same content is shown.

How can I prevent either Webtrends to stoop adding this or make Google not crawl these parameters? I have seen some ideas but not found a real answer I can use:

1. Add self-referral
2. noindex on parameter "WT.xx=.*"
3. Add the parameters after crawl with JavaScript
4. Add the parameter to a meta-tag

I am not so familiar with which method I can use and is the best?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly noindex parametrized urls. X-Robots-Tag is my preferred way to go.

Then, after you realized, parametrized urls are already out of index, block them against crawling through robots.txt, with something like `Disallow: *?*`

Comment: Hi, thanks for input. But adding X-Robots-Tag must be added at individual pages. In the CMS there is only one page but in Google Crawl there are 2 because the parameter added in link AFTER webtrends is loaded. So i cannot go in CMS and add this to the main page?

Comment: Using `X-Robots-Tag` for no index will prevent those pages from contributing any SEO value.   There are clearly links into them.   There are better options than this.